# How can i trace bytecode instructions in v8 library

Tags: node.js, v8, embedded-v8, libv8

I'm using the v8 library to run JavaScript code in C++-project. And I want to log every bytecode instruction at run time.
Is it possible or not? Or can I only log the assembly instructions? And if I can, then how? 
The trace log is required, not the result of disassembling bytecode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you build with the `V8_TRACE_IGNITION` symbol defined (by putting `v8_enable_trace_ignition = true` into your `args.gn`), you can then use the flag `--trace-ignition`.

Note that V8 optimizes hot functions after a while, at which point they'll no longer run in the interpreter and hence will no longer be traced. For your purposes, you can turn that off with `--noopt`; of course doing so will significantly degrade performance of computationally intensive programs (10x slower wouldn't be unexpected; the exact number depends a lot on what the code is doing).

Also, please be aware that counting bytecode instructions will be a very coarse approximation of program complexity. For example, a single bytecode could call a builtin that does an arbitrarily expensive operation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the d8 shell you can pass the flag `--print-bytecode`.

If you are embedding v8, you could set `i::FLAG_print_bytecode = true` before creating the isolate. You could check out [test-api.cc](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/v8/test/cctest/test-api.cc) for more examples of using the API.

Comment: Thank you. But I do not need the result of decompiling bytecode, namely the log of its execution. List of all executed bytecode instructions. I do not know if it's possible .

Comment: We want to evaluate the complexity of JavaScript code by the number and types of bytecode instructions executed.