# How to get Node.js to trace ignition within v8? with --trace-ignition

Tags: node.js, v8

The version of Node.js I used is 10.21.0. I modified BUILD.gn under deps/v8 folder: I set V8_TRACE_IGNITION=true and I rebuilt Node.js using ./configure after that. Then I run "node --trace-ignition xx.js". I expected to trace the ignition's behavior. But it said bad option. I was wondering where I did wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i trace bytecode instructions in v8 library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49899664/how-can-i-trace-bytecode-instructions-in-v8-library)

Comment: thanks for replying. I didn't find args.gn file in v8. I modified build.gn in v8. I think they work the same but maybe I am wrong. Still getting the same error

Comment: You seemed to misread it, and used the wrong option, but focused on the file name in that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering where I did wrong.

To get an answer to that, you'd have to describe *exactly* what you've done, e.g. by posting the patch showing your edits to the file.

That said, modifying `BUILD.gn` is not necessary to get `--trace-ignition` to work. Simply use `gn args out/<your_output_dir>` to edit your build settings as usual, and add `v8_enable_trace_ignition = true`.